# Recursive InvokeOnMainThread block

Tags: c#, delegates, xamarin.ios

I would like to know what is a recommended way to deal with situations where (Begin)InvokeOnMainThread calls are called recursively.

The scenario is this... I have a UI button press that launches a download and the download launches an audio playback and the audio playback changes the UI.

The code looks something like this:

```
void ButtonPressHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> {
    StartDownload(CompletionHandler);
 });
}

void CompletionHandler()
{
 BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> {
    StartPlayback(PlaybackFinished);
 });
}


void PlaybackFinished()
{
 BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> {
    UpdateUI();
 });
}
```

What is the recommended way to deal with this situation? My UI doesn't get updated. I tried BeginInvokeOnMainThread and InvokeOnMainThread. Can there be a deadlock situation?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work. In the download complete I used row.GetActiveCell of my tableview to use it to update the UI. That seems to work compared to GetCell which didnt change the UI even if I do SetNeedsDisplay. Not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not a problem with "recursive" BeginOnMainThread calls, but something else. Here are a few tips to check:

- Is UpdateUI actually called?
- What happens if you call UpdateUI for each step in the process? Where does it stop working?
- Does UpdateUI actually work if you call it from ButtonPressHandler?

Comment: My Update does SetNeedsDisplay of image and text in a UITableViewCell. If I do it in the first InvokeOnMainThread it works. If i call it on the inside InvokeOnMainThread it doesnt do anything. If I do a tableview cell update it works always regardless of InvokeOnMainThread.

Comment: To check the threading I print the thread id inside the Update UI function and it always returns the UI thread. But If I call update UI inside the the outer block the update works but doesnt work inside the  inner block.

Comment: Basically here is my use case. I have a button that upon pressed will update the ui, then create a webclient and start a download asynchronously. Then when the download is complete, it will need to update the ui again. The first update works, but the second update to reset the text and button image doesnt. I have tried using Performselector or CreateScheduledTimer to no avail.

Comment: @VahidKowsari: your scenario should work, so it is likely something in the rest of your code which is causing this behavior. Maybe you can try creating a small test project to show the problem?

Comment: Thanks Rolf. I did a small test app that does test the functionality above with a button to start and a label for the UI change and it seems to work. The difference between this and my real app is that my app does this inside a custom UITableViewCell. This might be contributing to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

InvokeOnMainThread will suspend the execution of your thread, and wait for the delegate to be executed on the main thread. When that completes, the thread resumes execution. 
BeginInvokeOnMainThread does not.

Have you tried something like this?

```
void ButtonPressHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (NSThread.Current.IsMainThread)
        StartDownload(CompletionHandler);
    else
        BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => StartDownload(CompletionHandler););        
}
```

... and so on for the others methods.